# Issue with GUI - items won't display

Tags: java, user-interface

please excuse my incompetence, I have just recently gained an interest for programming. I'll try and be as concise as possible.

Basically, I have written the following code:

Main: http://pastebin.com/jTqrA3tL
Support: http://pastebin.com/66gg7sK8

Problem: My JTextField labeled "item" won't show up? What have I done wrong? Is there something I need to add? All help would be appreciated, but please do not bash my "code" too hard.

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site. Please don't post links, but rather post your code here. We're volunteers and greatly appreciate your taking the effort to make it easy to answer your question.

Comment: Do `frame.setVisible(true);` **after** you add text field to the frame.

Answer (score 0):

**problem:**

```
  frame.setSize(300,100);
  frame.setVisible(true);
  setLayout(new FlowLayout());
  item = new JTextField("Lorem Ipsum ", 10);
  add(item);
```

You are trying to add the item after you `setVisible` to true thus it is not displaying

**solution:**

add the item first then set your frame to visibility to true

```
     frame.setSize(300,100);
     setLayout(new FlowLayout());
     item = new JTextField("Lorem Ipsum ", 10);
     add(item);
     frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Thank you! Really helpful. However, this seems somewhat sloppy if I later would like to add more items. Is there any way to set the visibility in the main class?